# JWPlayer metadata events undefined

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Does anyone know why the metadata properties of `on('bufferChange')` and `on('meta')` events are undefined on mobile devices? It works like charm on the desktop, but it doesn't  on the mobile browsers for iPhone, Windows Phone or Android.
Here's the code I've used:

```
<div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");

    playerInstance.setup({
      file: "//the video source"
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      primary: "html5",
      autostart: false,
    });

    playerInstance.on('bufferChange', function(ev) {
         //ev.metadata undefined
    });
    playerInstance.on('meta', function(ev) {
         //ev.metadata undefined
    });
```

EDIT:

I can't post the link to the real stream, but I'v used the following test stream as well which doesn't work either: http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch2/appleman.m3u8

The event was either undefined or the values (e.g. ev.metadata.bandwidth) were NaN.

I've tested this on an iPhone 5c (Safari,iOS up to date), a Lumia 640 (Stock browser - IE, seems like IE-engine does not support HLS at all due to missing WebKit, OS up to date), and an Galaxy S6 Edge (Chrome Browser, OS up to date).

Answer (score 1):

Some of this information may be dependent on the use of our HLS Flash plugin, given that we can only provide what the native browser returns to us. Is there any more information that you can provide about the stream, operating systems, or browser that you're testing this on? If so, we are happy to update the documentation with additional information on compatibility/browser discrepancy.

Timed metadata is exposed with JW 7.3 on iOS (recently pushed to staging). We will be updating our example on the support site when 7.3 is pushed to production:
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1459607-example-using-timed-metadata

Comment: Please excuse my late response, I've updated my answer. Appreciate your support!